# How to use the "Function type" fans

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, fan

I have these [AFB0824GHE-R00](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/632/AFB80x80x38mm-515930.pdf) Fans in my hands, and I see that there are three wires on that fan. The + and -, and the third blue wire, which according to the datasheet's hint is a function wire?

[image: fan function wire]

[image: function type]

I am not sure how to use it. If I let it floating, the fans work as normal (I connect + and - to 24V and they spin), and I havent connect the blue wire to any voltage potential, as I may fry the fans by mistake.

So is this a wire that activates a "function" mode of the fan?

Where should I connect this wire to enable this mode, and what this mode does?

Comment: The *datasheet* does mention it. That link is just not the datasheet, but just some sales brochure.

Comment: @Justme yup, you're right. [This one](https://www.delta-fan.com/Download/Spec/AFB0824GHE-R00.pdf) does mention it.

Comment: Rotation detection R, open collector 00

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the fan datasheet, that specific model has a motor lock detection, and the third wire is an open collector output of the lock detector.

It will be pulled low when motor runs, and high-z when motor is locked. Max ratings for external pull-up voltage and current are 26.4V and 5 mA.

If you don't intend to use the lock detection output, you don't need to connect it in any way.